# How to make Perl file operations platform-independent?

Tags: perl

I use Perl on Linux, but I started using `File::Spec->catfile` to make my perl code run on Windows as well, e.g.,

```
$tmp = File::Spec->catfile($ENV{HOME}, "tmp");
```

instead of

```
$tmp = "$ENV{HOME}/tmp";
```

But how can I make the following code portable:

```
my @files = <$ENV{HOME}/tmp/*>;
```

It uses slashes as file separators, so I assume it won't work on Windows. And I don't see how to use `File::Spec->catfile` in that expression?

Comment: Perl recognizes slashes `/` as file separators, even on Windows.

Comment: @TLP: Actually Windows itself recognizes `/` as a separator.  But `$ENV{HOME}` isn't likely to be set on a Windows system.

Comment: Cool. What is `catfile` even be used for, then? Are there other systems on which the `/` doesn't work?

Comment: @TLP, Perl just passes the paths to the system. Outside of modules like File::Spec and File::Basename, it doesn't know or care that "/" is a file separator.

Comment: @ikegami: And, just maybe, some future system that your code will eventually be ported to.

Comment: @Keith Thompson, that's not likely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `catfile` just returns a string that can be used as a file name, you can do something like this (untested):

```
$tmp = File::Spec->catfile($ENV{HOME}, "tmp", "*");
my @files = glob $tmp;
```

But `$ENV{HOME}` isn't likely to be set on a Windows system.

You might consider using [`File::Spec->tmpdir()`](http://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aSpec).

Comment: Ooh, good question!  It turns out that `<$tmp>` invokes `readline`, but `<$tmp >` is a `glob`, for reasons that probably aren't worth understanding.  Using the `glob` function explicitly is better; I'll update my answer.

Comment: Using `bsd_glob` directly instead of via `glob` is actually better.

Comment: @ikegami: You mean `File::Glob::bsd_glob` rather than the built-in `glob` function?  I didn't know about that.  Can the reasons why it's better be stated (or linked) briefly enough for a comment?  I tend to think that using the built-in is cleaner unless there's some specific advantage.

Comment: @Keith Thompson, Yeah, they're the same function. Depending on how you call it (via `glob` or not), it handles spaces differently. `glob` really mishandles spaces based on how must people use `glob`. Working as intended is major specific advantage :)

Answer (score 4):

The [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) function can be used:

```
my @files = glob File::Spec->catfile( $ENV{'HOME'}, 'tmp', '*' );
```

As the other comments have stated, Perl works with `/` in Windows. However, to make it more portable, I will consider the above usage.

Comment: It isn't Perl that works with forward slashes, it is the Windows OS itself that works fine with forward slashes (it is only the Windows *shell* that requires backward slashes)

Comment: @tadmc, Lots of shell commands accept "/" too (`dir`, `cd`), but many require that it's quoted to avoid ambiguity with options.